# How can I loop over the output of a shell command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to write a script that loops through the output (array possibly?) of a shell command, `ps`.

Here is the command and the output:

```
$ ps -ewo pid,cmd,etime | grep python | grep -v grep | grep -v sh
 3089 python /var/www/atm_securit       37:02
17116 python /var/www/atm_securit       00:01
17119 python /var/www/atm_securit       00:01
17122 python /var/www/atm_securit       00:01
17125 python /var/www/atm_securit       00:00
```

Convert it into bash script (snippet):

```
for tbl in $(ps -ewo pid,cmd,etime | grep python | grep -v grep | grep -v sh)
do
   echo $tbl
done
```

But the output becomes:

```
3089
python
/var/www/atm_securit
38:06
17438
python
/var/www/atm_securit
00:02
17448
python
/var/www/atm_securit
00:01
```

How do I loop through every row like in the shell output, but in a bash script?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Never `for` loop over the results of a shell command if you want to process it line by line unless you are changing the value of the *internal field separator* `$IFS` to `\n`. This is because the lines will get subject of *word splitting* which leads to the actual results you are seeing. Meaning if you for example have a file like this:

```
foo bar
hello world
```

The following for loop

```
for i in $(cat file); do
    echo "$i"
done
```

gives you:

```
foo
bar
hello
world
```

Even if you use `IFS='\n'` the lines might still get subject of [*Filename expansion*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html)

---

I recommend to use `while` + `read` instead because `read` reads line by line.

Furthermore I would use `pgrep` if you are searching for pids belonging to a certain binary. However, since python might appear as different binaries, like `python2.7` or `python3.4` I suggest to pass `-f` to `pgrep` which makes it search the whole command line rather than just searching for binaries called `python`. But this will also find processes which have been started like `cat foo.py`. You have been warned! At the end you can refine the regex passed to `pgrep` like you wish.

Example:

```
pgrep -f python | while read -r pid ; do
    echo "$pid"
done
```

or if you also want the process name:

```
pgrep -af python | while read -r line ; do
    echo "$line"
done
```

If you want the process name and the pid in separate variables:

```
pgrep -af python | while read -r pid cmd ; do
    echo "pid: $pid, cmd: $cmd"
done
```

You see, [`read`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/bash.1.html#shell%20builtin%20commands) offers a flexible and stable way to process the output of a command line-by-line.

---

Btw, if you prefer your `ps .. | grep` command line over `pgrep` use the following loop:

```
ps -ewo pid,etime,cmd | grep python | grep -v grep | grep -v sh \
  | while read -r pid etime cmd ; do
    echo "$pid $cmd $etime"
done
```

Note how I changed the order of `etime` and `cmd`. Thus to be able to read `cmd`, which can contain whitespace, into a single variable. This works because `read` will break down the line into variables, as many times as you specified variables. The remaining part of the line - possibly including whitespace - will get assigned to the last variable which has been specified in the command line.

Comment: I am assuming you meant 'pgrep' not 'prep' ?

Comment: Oh, sure....... Btw, if you need the etime, use `ps -p "$pid" -o etime` in the loop. Of course you can also use your `ps .. | grep ` command line, but still pipe that to `while read ...` ...

Comment: Even if you set `IFS`, the expansion of the command substitution is still subject to pathname expansion, so the `for` loop is just plain wrong.

Comment: There are a couple of possible problems with the `cmd | while read` approach, depending on what's inside the loop: the while loop runs in a subshell, so variables etc it sets don't live past the end of the loop, and if anything in the loop reads from stdin, it'll consume the command output. If these cause trouble, you can use `while read -u3 -r ... done 3< <(cmd)` instead. But the `<( ... )` construct is not portable to all shells, so be sure to start the script with a bash-only shebang (`#!/bin/bash`, *not* `#!/bin/sh`)

Comment: @GordonDavisson Sure, if the code inside the while loop should run in the scope of the current shell we need to use process substitution instead of piping into `while read`. If a command inside the while loop reads from stdin I suggest to redirect `< /dev/tty` into the command, if applicable. But your suggestion is also a good point! At the end it depends. I don't wanted to extend the answer too much and I see generally more problems with a `for` loop.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Even in POSIX, the problem can be overcome with named pipes, for which process substitution merely provides a convenient syntax for managing.

Answer (score 14):

I found you can do this just use double quotes:

```
while read -r proc; do
     #do work
done <<< "$(ps -ewo pid,cmd,etime | grep python | grep -v grep | grep -v sh)"
```

This will save each line to the array rather than each item.

Comment: This will put the entire output from the command in a single element of the array.

Comment: @EtanReisner Thank you for the catch.

Comment: Why the `<<<` instead of just `<` ?

Comment: @Roland [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/678915/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-bash) is an awesome answer on `<<<` vs `<<` vs `<`

Comment: This is giving me a redirection error in Ubuntu

Comment: @San I am unable to replicate your error in Ubuntu using the syntax above

Comment: @jkdba I tried on Ubuntu 18.04 and 20 but seems like it's not able to run <<< and giving me Syntax Error: `redirection expected`

Comment: @San I tested on 20.04.2 LTS no problem.

Answer (score 9):

When using `for` loops in bash it splits the given list by default by `whitespaces`, this can be adapted by using the so called *Internal Field Seperator*, or `IFS` in short .

> IFS The Internal Field Separator that is used for word splitting after
>   expansion and to split lines into words with the read builtin command.
>   The default value is "".

For your example we would need to tell `IFS` to use `new-lines` as break point.

```
IFS=$'\n'

for tbl in $(ps -ewo pid,cmd,etime | grep python | grep -v grep | grep -v sh)
do
   echo $tbl
done
```

This example returns the following output on my machine.

```
  668 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/ud    03:05:54
27892 python                            00:01
```

Comment: The command substitution is still subject to pathname expansion. [Do it right](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001), and use a `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another bash-based solution, inspired by comment of @[Gordon Davisson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89817/gordon-davisson).

For this we need (atleast bash [v1.13.5](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/49940/367237) (1992) or later verison), because [Process-Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html)<sup>[2](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst),[3](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html#PROCESS-SUB),[4](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html#PSUBP)</sup> `while read var; do { ... }; done < <(...);`, etc are used.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -a oL ; do {  # reads single/one line
    echo "${oL}";  # prints that single/one line
};
done < <(ps -ewo pid,cmd,etime | grep python | grep -v grep | grep -v sh);
unset oL;
```

Note: You can use any simple or complex command/command-set inside the `<(...)` which may have multiple output lines.
And what code does what function is shown [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/607424/367237).

And here is a single/one-liner way:
`while IFS= read -a oL ; do { echo "${oL}"; }; done < <(ps -ewo pid,cmd,etime | grep python | grep -v grep | grep -v sh); unset oL;`

( As Process-Substitution is not part of POSIX yet So its not supported in many POSIX compliant shell or in POSIX shell mode of bash-shell. Process-Substitution existed in bash since 1992 (so that is 28yrs ago from now/2020), & existed in ksh86 (before 1985)<sup>[1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49918/)</sup>. So POSIX should've included it. )
If you or any user wants to use something similar as Process-Substitution in POSIX compliant shell (i.e: sh, ash, dash, pdksh/mksh, etc), then look into [NamedPipes](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/NamedPipes).